Assignment to a prvalue in C++
I was exploring a cppreference page about value categories and found some strange syntax in an example (the second extended content):
#include <iostream>
 
struct S
{
    S() : m{42} {}
    S(int a) : m{a} {}
    int m;
};
 
int main()
{
    S s;
 
    // Expression `S{}` is prvalue
    // May appear on the right-hand side of an assignment expression
    s = S{};
 
    std::cout << s.m << '\n';
 
    // Expression `S{}` is prvalue
    // Can be used on the left-hand side too
    std::cout << (S{} = S{7}).m << '\n';
}

Look at the last line of main(). There is an assignment S{} = S{7} that is very awkward. We can do this even simpler:
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int m = 1;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << (S{} = S{}).m << '\n';
}

Compiler shows no warning or errors and everything is completely fine. That could be okay, but I think the documentation says it must be impossible. Quoting the same page:

An rvalue can't be used as the left-hand operand of the built-in assignment or compound assignment operators.

I guess S{} is a prvalue, and all other conditions are met also. So, how does C++ converts this prvalue into an lvalue?

S{} = S{} does not use the built-in assignment. It calls the implicitly defined S::operator=.

Look at temporary materialization

The quote says "built-in assignment".
You are not using a built-in assignment. The built-in assignment operator operates on non-class types. You are using the assignment operator overload S& operator=(S&&); implicitly-declared as non-static member function of S. In other words, after overload resolution S{} = S{} is equivalent to
S{}.operator=(S{})

Calling a non-static member function (without reference-qualifiers) on a prvalue is permitted. It behaves just like binding the S{} parameter in the argument to the reference parameter: A temporary object of type S is created and initialized from the prvalue and this in the operator= overload refers to this temporary object, which lives until the end of the full-expression in which it was created.
Of course, that assignment is usually pointless, because the temporary object is destroyed at the end of the expression and so it doesn't matter what you assign to it. But sometimes it is useful to be able to chain member function calls on functions that return by-value, i.e. prvalues, if at the end only some result of the last member function call is needed. That's why it is allowed and permits this use without having to name each intermediate class object.

It will be great if you provide a link or quote some documentation page/other source about what exactly built-in assignment is. A page on the operator mention nothing class or non-class objects in the section "Built-in simple assignment operator". Also there is a notion of direct assignment, but it is for non-class types only.
I understand that in my code listing a default operator is called. My only goal is to understand if the quotation about rvalues contradicts with the example.

@МаксимФомин I don't know whether cppreference spells it out somewhere explicitly, but the relevant part of the standard is [expr.pre]/3. [expr.compound] describes the behavior of the built-in operators only.

If a non-built-in operator is chosen according to the rules of [over.match.oper], then the expression is rewritten in the way I suggested above. It also has its operands rewritten if a built-in operator is chosen that requires conversions on the operands, so that in the end the built-in candidate ([over.built]) itself only ever works on types for which they are specified in [expr.compound]. If you look through [expr.compound] and take account of [over.built] you'll see that the built-in operators only ever apply to non-class types.

But the simplified important take-away should be that whenever an operator has at least one operand that has a class type, then overload resolution is performed for the operator to potentially select a corresponding operator overload. If one is selected, then the expression is rewritten to a function call expression to that overload and only then is the expression further analysed. That way there may no assignment operator left after the overload resolution. "Built-in operator" refers to the behavior of operators as described in [expr.compound] after this overload resolution is applied.

For historical reasons, the assignment operator the compiler generates by default is S &operator=(S &&); and NOT S &operator=(S &&) &; as one might expect.  That means that you can call it on a prvalue without any error.
You can "fix" this by adding
S &operator=(S &&) & = default;

to your class definition.  You probably also want
S &operator=(const S&) & = default;

those two should be the default (IMO) but for historical reasons (going back to before the introduction of rvalue types and move semantics) they are not.
